# Is "Firestarter" something that native a English speaker would think as negative?

Tags: meaning

I'm thinking of Firestarter as a name for an upcoming software project. However, I justed Googled it and as it turns out, Urban Dictionary says it's [when two males rub their *parts* together](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=firestarter&ei=EDPsUr2qCsPtkQez0oGIDQ&usg=AFQjCNHs6Up2743O7HE_6My-g1FDu66C-g&sig2=dx3a6ZtHaUhbnriOlDU4xw).

Can I use this name without fearing someone is gonna look at it negatively?

Comment: I think this is POB (too subjective). fwiw, ***firelighters*** were an ordinary household commodity in my youth, and I'm sure they still are to many today.

Comment: Or you could call it Zippo, after the lighter.

Comment: Just goes to show you learn something every day!

Comment: @Oldcat: As I remember, the brandname of the paraffin wax sticks I had to use (as the official designated house firestarter) was actually ***Zip***. I didn't discover ***Zippos*** until many years later.

Comment: Like some other commenters, I have never heard of a firestarter in the sense given by Urban Dictionary (and I consider myself relatively well-versed in gay slang). My immediate association to the word is the song _Firestarter_ by the Prodigy, and I would venture that between the Stephen King book and movie and the Prodigy song, you'll have most people's immediate associations covered.

Comment: @WS2 I wish I could unlearn it!

Comment: If there's a word or phrase in English that some teenager somewhere hasn't corrupted into a sexual double entendre, I haven't run across it yet.

Comment: Apart from its possible meaning and implications, *firestarter* is already the name of at least one software for animation: http://www.coffeecup.com/firestarter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, its  commonest other non-sexual connotation is that of a mystical arsonist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't understand if "firestarter" is more known for it's sexual connotation or something else.

Comment: I had never heard your sexual reference.  "Firestarter" was a  book by Stephen King and later a movie.

Comment: I'll take that as a "no, it's more known as something that something that starts something, or a pyromaniac, or a Stephen King book or movie". Thank you